# msql replace links in database

Tags: sql, replace

I have again problem with multiple rows in db. They are about 40k rows which need to be replaced to new link. What i want is to add some text after whole link which is saved into db. My example:

```
UPDATE Stores SET MapView = REPLACE(MapView,'&a=b','http://link.com/xy');
```

But this doesnt work affcourse, it replaces whole link with a, what i want is to get like that: http://link.com/xy&a=b
Any chance to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this?

```
UPDATE Stores SET MapView = concat(MapView,'&a=b');
```